SSIS Export Data Containing Long 15k Field Values to Excel
The Issue
I need to set up a task to export data contained in a view to an Excel table and then upload this to an FTP.
I have done this before using SSIS and then a WinSCP script which is normally quite straightforward until you find one of the fields is over 256 characters which is when things start to get frustrating due to SSIS determining an inappropriately small column is required for the data and then failing when trying to export. In this table some values are up to 15k characters.
The error you then receive is:
An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "SomeLongColumn" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT".

What Didn't Fix It
I then right-click the OLE DB Source and Excel Destination and go to the advanced editor and try changing data types in the input and output properties to more appropriate field sizes then try again and find Visual Studio has changed them all back again so then on the properties for the OLE DB Source and Excel Destination you can set the ValidateExternalMetadata to false and DelayValidation to true on the connections and this stops giving the warnings and leaves things as they are but it still fails with data errors.
I also tried adding IMEX=1; MAXROWSTOSCAN=0 onto the connection string for the Excel file to try to stop it scanning the file and adjusting itself.
This did leave my field settings in place but it still failed with the same error.
What Did Fix It (Sort Of)
What works in the end is opening the Excel file in Excel, adding a line to the top on row 2 under the header and giving the long fields in this row the largest values of all other rows (I copied and pasted the longest value from another row). I could just order the rows by length of field in descending order if it was just one long field but there were 6.
Then when I tried again, SSIS checks this top row and adjusts itself accordingly and exports data to the Excel file so I thought it was resolved but I realise it is appending data each time but I want it to refresh/replace the data each time.
Why It Still Doesn't Solve It
Each time I run the task it appends data to the same Excel file so in order to get it to replace data I added an Execute SQL Task where the code is DROP TABLE 'Sheet1$' to remove the sheet in the Excel file then another task creates the table setting the long fields to NTEXT but then with the Excel file empty it is back to the same error about the data types and if I add a large row to the spreadsheet manually then this fixes it and it exports without errors again but if I remove the row again it errors.
The Workaround
I need to leave 1 dummy row in the Excel file with long values that exceed or match the longest real data in that column so was able to use a copy file task to remove the file with full data in it and replace it with a file with the 1 dummy line in it as the Excel Connection Manager doesn't support the DELETE command to remove the rows.
This sort of works as the dummy line must then be ignored by the system that picks up and uses this file but this is all very flaky and what should be a straightforward task given all elements to this are Microsoft products (MSSQL, VS, SSIS, Excel) isn't but all this is about is trying to get SSIS to realise the Excel column needs to store large values which they are capable of doing.
Really it shouldn't check the current destination column sizes and just write the data from the source but I can't seem to get it to do that meaning I need to leave this dummy line in the file and then build something at the other end to filter this one row out of the data. Also in future if a new row ends up being longer than this dummy row I think it may fall over again with a need to make the dummy row data even longer.
Is there something I am missing or should I give up and approach this a different way?

should I give up and approach this a different way? Yes, probably. The ACE drivers have never been practical for large data types. You might have better luck using EPPlus and orchestrating it from .NET or PowerShell. Bonus: you could use the WinSCP assemblies directly from .NET or PowerShell to upload your resultant files and not have to launch and manage additional processes. (I'm not affiliated with EPPlus Software but have used their tools successfully for years.)

Yeah, i agree with above, microsoft excel import "wizard" made me prematurely grey. If you use java, i found poi libs to be very stable for excel work, and they don't need the IMEX nonsense

Honestly, I would look to exporting those 15,000+ character values entirely separately. Like others, I avoid Excel like the plague (I often go with CSV or JSON), but if you want to also provide a 15,000+ character value, i feel like that it would be better™ to provide individual text files for those values, one for each row, and have appropriate details in the data export to denote which file it is (or name the export files appropriately).

Based on comments and after spending a day and a half fiddling about with something that should not be this difficult and flaky I managed to write some C# code that will take any table/view and output it as an Excel file in about an hour so sharing it here in case others end up in the same position (wish I had started with this approach first!).
It reads column names and the number of columns and rows dynamically so no need to manually hard code anything and if you added a new column to your view it would automatically get picked up.
Create a new Visual Studio Console app (I used .NET 9) and in Package Manager add the required packages for SQL Server and Excel:
Install-Package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
Install-Package NPOI

Replace the contents of Program.cs with:
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;

var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    DataSource = "SERVER_NAME_HERE",
    UserID = "USERNAME_HERE",
    Password = "PASSWORD_HERE",
    InitialCatalog = "DATABASE_HERE",
    TrustServerCertificate = true
};

var connectionString = builder.ConnectionString;

try
{
    //Database Connection
    await using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    Console.WriteLine("\nExport SQL View to Excel File");
    Console.WriteLine("=========================================\n");
    Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Database\n");

    await connection.OpenAsync();
    Console.WriteLine($"\nConnected to {builder.DataSource}");

    var sql =
        @"SELECT *
        FROM VIEW_HERE";

    await using var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    await using var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();


    Console.WriteLine("Loading Data into Excel\n");
    //Excel File from NPOI
    var book = new XSSFWorkbook();
    var sheet = book.CreateSheet("Sheet1");

    //Cell Styles
    var cellStyleDate = book.CreateCellStyle();
    cellStyleDate.DataFormat = book.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    var cellStyleTime = book.CreateCellStyle();
    cellStyleTime.DataFormat = book.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat("HH:mm");
    var cellStyleCurrency = book.CreateCellStyle();
    cellStyleCurrency.DataFormat = book.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat("£#,0");

    int line = 0;
    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        //Add top row with column names
        if (line == 0)
        {
            var topRow = sheet.CreateRow(line);

            for (int cell = 0; cell < reader.FieldCount; cell++)
            {
                var headerCell = topRow.CreateCell(cell);
                headerCell.SetCellValue(reader.GetName(cell));
            }

            line++;
        }
        
        //Add data underneath
        var row = sheet.CreateRow(line);
        
        for (int cell = 0; cell < reader.FieldCount; cell++)
        {
            var bodyCell = row.CreateCell(cell);
            if (reader.IsDBNull(cell) == true)
            {
                bodyCell.SetCellValue("");
            }
            else if (reader.GetFieldType(cell) == typeof(Int32))
            {
                bodyCell.SetCellValue(reader.GetInt32(cell));
            }
            else if (reader.GetFieldType(cell) == typeof(Decimal))
            {
                bodyCell.SetCellValue((double)reader.GetDecimal(cell));
                bodyCell.CellStyle = cellStyleCurrency;
            }
            else if (reader.GetFieldType(cell) == typeof(string))
            {
                bodyCell.SetCellValue(reader.GetString(cell));
            }
            else if (reader.GetFieldType(cell) == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                DateTime dateTimeValue = reader.GetDateTime(cell);
                bodyCell.SetCellValue(dateTimeValue);

                //If Date is default then value only contains time element
                if (dateTimeValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") == "1900-01-01")
                {
                    bodyCell.CellStyle = cellStyleTime;
                }
                else
                {
                    bodyCell.CellStyle = cellStyleDate;
                }
                
            }
            else
            {
                bodyCell.SetCellValue(reader.GetString(cell));
            }
        }

        line++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Saving Excel file");
    using (var fileStream = File.Create("c:\EXPORT_FOLDER_HERE\FILE_HERE.xlsx"))
    {
        book.Write(fileStream);
        Console.WriteLine($"File Saved to {fileStream.Name}");
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}

Now run save and run and it should export your file to the chosen folder.
It might make sense to set this up as Windows Authentication an supply the desired Excel folder and file and database server name and database name as input parameters and run as a user with appropriate permissions then it could be re-used for future tasks.
EDIT
I have now published a project to GitHub where I have developed the idea above further published an initial release and I created one for exporting from SQL to Excel and another for exporting from Excel to SQL.
The source code is included as well so you can check the files are safe etc or compile them yourself in Visual Studio.
With my test file with the very long values I was able to just input the details of the Excel file and SQL table and run the program without any additional setup.
https://github.com/robinwilson16/ExcelSQLExporter
https://github.com/robinwilson16/ExcelSQLImporter
You will need the .NET 9 runtime installed first.
